# How to find the cell background color

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

Using Flexgrid

I want to check the background color of the particular cell...

Code

```
if flexgrid1.TextMatrix(1, 2).CellBackColor = vbCyan then
msgbox vbcyan
else
msgbox vbwhite
End if
```

The above code is showing error as "Invalid Qualifier"

Other way....

```
if flexgrid1.row = 1 and flexgrid1.col = 2 and  .CellBackColor = vbCyan then
    msgbox vbcyan
    else
    msgbox vbwhite
    End if
```

The above code not displayed message box

How to solve the problem...

What wrong in my code.

Comment: There is no CellBackColor property for the TextMatrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.CellBackColor` gets/sets the color for the current `.Row`/`.Col`, so before asking, you have to set the `.Row`/`.Col` to the one you're looking at:

```
With flexgrid1
   .Row = 1
   .Col = 2
   If .CellBackColor = vbCyan Then
      msgbox vbCyan
   Else
      msgbox vbWhite
   End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

are your msgbox statements kosher? msgbox takes a string as its argument.

```
msgbox "colour is Cyan"
```

Comment: msgbox vbCyan will show a message box with 16776960 (the numeric value for the vbCyan constant).

Comment: if that is what you want why bother with the if statement. msgbox .CellBackColor